# Include bibliography of xr (xcite) citations, that only contains the relevant entries

Tags: bibliographies, numbering, citing, external-files, xr

**Short description of my Question:**

I am using the `xr` or `xcite` package in my derivative project `supplementary.tex` to give references/citations the same number that they already have in an external document `main.tex`. However, doing this will not display the bibliography in the supplementary. How can I display the bibliography also in the supplementary file, only showing the entries that have actually been cited in the supplementary? (So that it looks like the image under "Goal" below.)

**Example:**

[image]

```
% main.tex
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\section*{Main (External) Document}
Main document with many citations \cite{Chomsky1957, Chomsky1965, Knuth1984texbook}.

\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{mybib}

\end{document}
```

[image]

```
% supplementary.tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xr}                % or \usepackage{xcite}
\externaldocument{main}        % or \externalcitedocument{main}

\begin{document}
\section*{Supplementary Document}
Supplementary document that only contains some of the main references from the main document \cite{Knuth1984texbook}.
\end{document}
```

Bibliography data file:

```
% mybib.bib
@book{Knuth1984texbook,
    Author = {Knuth, D.E.},
    Title = {The \TeX book, volume A of Computers and typesetting},
    Publisher = {Addison-Wesley},
    Year = {1984},
}
@book{Chomsky1957,
    Address = {The Hague},
    Author = {Noam Chomsky},
    Publisher = {Mouton},
    Title = {Syntactic Structures},
    Year = {1957},
}
@book{Chomsky1965,
    Address = {Cambridge Mass.},
    Author = {Noam Chomsky},
    Publisher = {MIT Press},
    Title = {Aspects of the Theory of Syntax},
    Year = {1965},
}
```

This works very nicely (as long as the `main.aux` is generated in the same folder as the supplementary.tex), as can be seen in the images above.

However, I would like to include a list of References(Bibliography) also in the Supplementary Document, which only contains the references that I have actually cited in the Supplementary. I made an image with paint that shows what I want.

**Goal:**

[image]

How can I achieve this?

I already tried to use \bibliography{mybib} at the end of supplementary.tex. While this included a list of the references used in supplementary.tex (and no others), the citation numbers started again from 1 independent of their number in main.tex - basically undoing what xcite did.